# Multiple send from android service

Tags: android, service, http-post, alarmmanager

I use service with alarm manager to send data to my server. Code from service:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, onAlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, sId, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    int timeInterval = 14400;
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + timeInterval * 1000,
            timeInterval * 1000, pendingIntent);
```

In onAlarmReceiver I'm try to send info:

```
HTTPPoster.doPost(url, jsonToSendArray);

....


public static class HTTPPoster {
    public static HttpResponse doPost(String url, Object c) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        ((DefaultHttpClient) httpclient).setHttpRequestRetryHandler(new DefaultHttpRequestRetryHandler(0, false));
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
        HttpEntity entity;
        StringEntity s = new StringEntity(c.toString(), HTTP.UTF_8);            
        s.setContentType("application/json; charset=utf-8");
        s.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json; charset=utf-8"));
        entity = s;
        request.setEntity(entity);
        HttpResponse response;
        response = httpclient.execute(request);
        return response;
    }
}
```

And sometimes I get on server 10 simultaneous identical requests. How to solve this problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. make it thread safe
2. use timestamp of last request and check is delay before requests is correct